# PDF file search then display that page only

Tags: pdf

I create a PDF file with 20,000 pages. Send it to a printer and individual pages are printed and mailed. These are tax bills to homeowners.

I would like to place the PDF file my web server.

When a customer inputs a unique bill number on a search page, a search for that specific page is started.

When the page within the PDF file is located, only that page is displayed to the requester.

There are other issues with security, uniqueness of bill number to search that can be worked out.

The main question is... 1: Can this be done   2: Is there third party program that is required.

I am a novice programmer and would like to try and do this myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but I would strongly recommend a different route. Instead of one 20,000 page document which might be great for printing, can you instead make 20,000 individual documents and just name them with something unique (bill number or whatever)? PDFs are document presentations and aren't suited for searching or even text information storage. There's no "words" or "paragraphs" and there's even no guarantee that text is written letter after letter. "Hello World" could be written "Wo", "He", "llo", "rld". Your customer's number might be "H1234567" but be written "1234567", "H". Text might be "in-page" but it also might be in form fields which adds to the complexity. There are many PDF libraries out there that try to solve these problems but if you can avoid them in the first your life will be much easier.

If you can't re-make the main document then I would suggest a compromise. Take some time now and use a library like [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) (Java) or [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) (.Net) to split the giant document into smaller documents arbitrarily named. Then try to write your text extraction logic using the same libraries to find your uniqueifiers in the documents and rename each document accordingly. This is really the only way that you can prove that your logic worked on every possible scenario.

Also, be careful with your uniqueifiers. If you have accounts like "H1234" and "H12345" you need to make sure that your search algorithm is aware that one is a subset (and therefore a match) of the other.

Finally, and this depends on how sensitive your client's data is, but if you're transporting very sensitive material I'd really suggest you spot-check every single document. Sucks, I know, I've had to do it. I'd get a copy of [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) and convert all of the PDFs to images and then just run them through a program that can show me the document and the file name all at once. Google Picasa works nice for this. You could also write a Photoshop action that cropped the document to a specific region and then just use Windows Explorer.